# Microphone doesn't work in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, microphone

I'm using Alsa. `arecord -l` gives me

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #
```

However, when I try to record `arecord -vvv -fdat /tmp/mic.wav`, nothing is saved (`aplay` plays nothing back`).

When I try out an online microphone test, all that is played back is a beep, indicating that my microphone isn't even recognized.

`pavucontrol` recognizes a microphone, but unmuting it and changing levels don't seem to change anything. `alsamixer` doesn't even recognize the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure I know is thus:

1. Run `arecord -l` to see what cards you have. I believe the syntax to choose card X is `hw:X`. It's also possible to choose subdevices, but I don't know the syntax right now.
2. Run `arecord --dump-hw-params -D hw:X` to get the hardware parameters that you may choose from, like sample size, number of channels, sampling rate, supported formats, ...
3. Run `arecord` or `ffmpeg` or whatever with some combination of the supported parameters. Warning: not all possible combinations of supported parameters will necessarily work or produce a good signal. So play with the options.

Regarding `alsamixer`, there is `F6` to bring up the menu for choosing the card.

Questions for the OP (as I'm not allowed to comment): what do you mean by "nothing is saved"? Does the file exist in the filesystem? Try `ls -l FILENAME` or `stat FILENAME`.

Comment: I tried what you said, still nothing. With regards to `alsamixer`, card 0 is the only card available. And for `arecord`, no file comes out.

Comment: @DUOLabs you need to edit your question and provide the outputs of all those commands if you want help, together with the command invocations.